# IO Exception: External server did not return any content

Tags: apex, webservices, integration, wsdl2apex

I have a window service that is password protected.I have generate Apex class from that window service WSDL.Now i am try to call the service using stub method its shows me a error message"IO ExCeption : External server did not return any content." because i think this window service is password protected whose username :"abc",Password :"password".so how i can make apex call using the credential?Where i will define username and password in stub.Code is given as follows ::

APEX CLASS GENERATED FROM APEX ::

```
    public class wwwMaterialiseBeErp 
    {    
      public class BasicHttpBinding_IExternalService 
      {

        public String endpoint_x = 'https://fathomcs.com/Streamics-test/External.svc';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.materialise.be/eRP','wwwMaterialiseBeErp','http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/','schemasMicrosoftCom200310Serializat','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eRP.ExternalService.Model','schemasDatacontractOrg200407ErpExte','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/eRP.ExternalService.Model.Base','schemasDatacontractOrg200407ErpExte1','http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays','schemasMicrosoftCom200310Serializat1','http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Materialise.eRP.Entities','schemasDatacontractOrg200407Materia'};

        public Integer GetQuotesByContactPersonCount(String contactPersonExternalId) {
            wwwMaterialiseBeErp.GetQuotesByContactPersonCount_element request_x = new wwwMaterialiseBeErp.GetQuotesByContactPersonCount_element();
            wwwMaterialiseBeErp.GetQuotesByContactPersonCountResponse_element response_x;
            request_x.contactPersonExternalId = contactPersonExternalId;
            Map<String, wwwMaterialiseBeErp.GetQuotesByContactPersonCountResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, wwwMaterialiseBeErp.GetQuotesByContactPersonCountResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[]{endpoint_x,
                'http://www.materialise.be/eRP/IQuoteService/GetQuotesByContactPersonCount',
                'http://www.materialise.be/eRP',
                'GetQuotesByContactPersonCount',
                'http://www.materialise.be/eRP',
                'GetQuotesByContactPersonCountResponse',
                'wwwMaterialiseBeErp.GetQuotesByContactPersonCountResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.GetQuotesByContactPersonCountResult;
        }
    }
    public class GetQuotesByContactPersonCount_element {
        public String contactPersonExternalId;
        private String[] contactPersonExternalId_type_info = new String[]{'contactPersonExternalId','http://www.materialise.be/eRP','string','0','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.materialise.be/eRP','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'contactPersonExternalId'};
    }
    public class GetQuotesByContactPersonCountResponse_element {
        public Integer GetQuotesByContactPersonCountResult;
        private String[] GetQuotesByContactPersonCountResult_type_info = new String[]{'GetQuotesByContactPersonCountResult','http://www.materialise.be/eRP','int','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://www.materialise.be/eRP','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'GetQuotesByContactPersonCountResult'};

}





And HERE IS THE STUB CLASS USED IN VFPAGES ::


public with sharing class WebserviceCall 

{

 public Double message {get; private set;}

  public PageReference hello() 

  {    

    wwwMaterialiseBeErp.BasicHttpBinding_IExternalService stub = new    wwwMaterialiseBeErp.BasicHttpBinding_IExternalService();
   // stub.clientCertName_x='';

    stub.clientCert_x='fathomcs';
    stub.clientCertPasswd_x='test';
    stub.timeout_x=60000;

    // Make the Web service call
    message = stub.GetQuotesByContactPersonCount('1213233');
    return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the problem is authentication, you will need to check with the service provider what authentication mechanism they will accept.

One common one is [basic access authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) (which is secure providing HTTPS is used as it appears to be). As this [Apex Web Services and Callouts](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Web_Services_and_Callouts) documentation explains, including this in the request can be as simple as just adding a header (with the below code assuming you have chosen to keep the username and password in a custom setting):

```
MyCustomSetting__c s = MyCustomSetting__c.getInstance()
String v = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(s.UserName__c + ':' + s.Password__c));
stub.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('Authorization', 'Basic ' + v);
```